# Locate system wide libraries in Rcpp Makevars

Tags: c++, r, cmake

I wrote a C++ package "P". It has an R interface package "RP", built using Rcpp. P used Make directly for compilation, but was switched to CMake for portability. CMake is used to find headers (let's call their collection HF) and static libraries (SL in the rest of the present post) for system wide libraries.

I want to update RP to be able to depend on the CMake evolution of P. In the C++ sources `RP/src/*.cpp`, HF elements are included, and of course SL are statically linked.

What is the best way to call CMake in `RP/src/Makevars` to retrieve the locations of HF and SL ? The point here is not to replace the build system of Rcpp, but to leverage the search capabilities of CMake.

At the moment, P (CMake version) and RP build on my machine, using absolute path references in `RP/src/Makevars` such as:

```
INC_NLOPT = /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2_2/include
LIB_NLOPT = /usr/local/Cellar/nlopt/2.4.2_2/lib/libnlopt.a
```

Since we use RP internaly at the moment, we can expect CMake, HF and SL to be installed on every machine we will deploy to.

Comment: Maybe that's really just a CMake question and not an Rcpp question.it

Comment: How enlightening.

Comment: I do not see why you need to be snarky. CMake is not mentioned once in  the [one official piece of documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) so if you decide to use it with R, you can't really call it our problem when it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Also, if you problem is nlopt, you may want to visit the [`nloptr` repo](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr) and maybe particularly [this issue](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr/issues/39).

Comment: It is not called your problem. It has been tagged with Rcpp to give context. If you have nothing to add, feel free to ignore.

Comment: Good luck with your endeavours. I removed the `rcpp` tag.

Comment: Here is a [GitHub query for CMake among (published) CRAN packages](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Acran+CMake&type=Code).  Maybe you find something there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create a `CMakeFileLists.txt` file in RP/src. In this file, a `Libvar` file containing the required library paths is written using CMake `file` command. `Libvar` is then included in Makevars using `include`.

A configure file at the root of the package is executed to ensure that `Libvar` is generated before every call to make by R.