# Call CMake from make to get system libraries paths

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a package P written in C++ in which I use CMake to find the path for some installed static libraries.

I have a wrapper package RP which depends on P, and must include the same headers and link against the same static libraries that P does.

However, RP **must** be built using make. I can also not edit a complete Makefile, but I can edit compilation variables in a Makevars file. Idealy, I would call CMake from Makevars, and add the paths here.

Is it possible to call CMake from make, and have it return the locations of the relevant system wide libraries ?

Note: this is an edited version of [Locate system wide libraries in Rcpp Makevars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289360/locate-system-wide-libraries-in-rcpp-makevars), to suit a more general audience.

Comment: Yo-dawg-tier idea: make make file of `RP` invoke cmake for `RP` (that is `RP` is also build with cmake but with thin make wrapper).

Comment: Actually I do not call make myself, I can edit a Makevars file in which I can edit compilation flags. My idea would be to call CMake from this Makevars. The call to make and the build targets are hidden.

Comment: Now this does not match question content. "RP must be built using make" is not the same as not being able to properly edit make scripts.

Comment: I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a file containing the required libraries in CMake (using the file command), and include it in the make file.